# Using isolate with shiny

Tags: r, shiny

The code below creates a skeletal shiny UI. When the "Colour Palette" dropdown is changed. The R console shows that both the observeEvent for input$colour_pal AND output$make_shape are called.

Is that because I am changing cvec and shiny auto runs output$make_shape so it is not out of date?

I wish that the "Colour Palette" dropdown only activates the observeEvent for input$colour_pal. I thought I could accomplish this using isolate, but I think I'm doing it wrong.

Please advise.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

# Define UI for slider demo app ----
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Knobs and Dials"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar to demonstrate various slider options ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: make_shape parameters - a
      sliderInput("aa", "a",
                  min = -2, max = 2,
                  value = 0, step = 0.01),

      # Input: make_shape parameters - b
      sliderInput("bb", "b",
                  min = -2, max = 2,
                  value = 0, step = 0.01),

      # Input: Colour Palette
      selectInput("colour_pal", "Colour Palette",
                  list(`Monochrome` = c("Orange", "Yellow", "Blue", "Grey"),
                       `Mixed` = c("Dark Green with Blue Streaks", 
                                   "Dark Green with Yellow Streaks"
                       )
                  )
      )
    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("make_shape")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic for slider examples ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Reactive expression to create data frame of all input values ----
  sliderValues <- reactive({

    data.frame(
      Name = c("a", "b"),
      Value = as.character(c(input$a,
                             input$b)),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  })

  # Show the values in an HTML table ----
  output$values <- renderTable({
    sliderValues()
  })


  set_colour <- function(){
    if (input$colour_pal == "Orange") {
      cvec <- heat.colors(2048)
    } else if (input$colour_pal == "Yellow") {
      cvec <- rainbow(2048, s = 1, v = 1, start = 0.03, end = 0.19, alpha = 1.0)
    } else if (input$colour_pal == "Blue") {
      cvec <- rainbow(2048, s = 1, v = 1, start = 0.48, end = 0.866, alpha = 1.0)
    } else if (input$colour_pal == "Grey") {
      cvec <- grey(seq(0, 1, length = 50))
    } else if (input$colour_pal == "Dark Green with Blue Streaks") {
      cvec <- rainbow(2048, s = 1, v = 0.4, start = 0.333, end = 0.7, alpha = 1.0)
    } else if (input$colour_pal == "Dark Green with Yellow Streaks") {
      yellow <- rainbow(2048, s = 1, v = 1, start = 0.03, end = 0.19, alpha = 1.0)
      dgb <- rainbow(2048, s = 1, v = 0.4, start = 0.333, end = 0.7, alpha = 1.0)
      dgb[1400: 2048] <- yellow[1400: 2048]
      cvec <- dgb
    }  
  }


  # Look for slider movement 
  observeEvent({
    input$aa
    input$bb
  }, {
    print("slider")
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE) 

  # Look for colour dropdown
  observeEvent({
    input$colour_pal
  }, {
    print("colour")
    cvec <- isolate(set_colour())
  })

  output$make_shape <- renderText({
    cvec <- set_colour()
    print("make_shape")
  })

}  
# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible example. However, I can see that you are calling set_colour() in renderText(), which means you have not isolated it.

Comment: It runs `make_shape` because there is a requirement to run it: you have told it to unconditionally render `textOutput`, so it does. I believe your `observeEvent(input$colour_pal, ...)` is run once because ... things start, and `observe*` functions are inherently aggressive in running (contrasting with `reactive*` functions which are inherently lazy). (BTW: it's generally preferred if you reduce your example to a *minimum* required to demonstrate your problem. For example, `library(tidyverse)` is required for none of your code; you don't use `input$aa` or `$bb` or the `"slider"` block.)

Comment: `isolate` doesn't *reduce* reactivity, it keeps accessing that variable (the one time it is within `isolate`) from causing/cascading reactivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that because I am changing cvec [...]?

For this specific example, `cvec` does nothing (you might be aware of this already):

- it is a local variable in `set_colour` and its value is returned by that function by pure chance (last assignment is always to `cvec` for all `if` branches); it helps if your function / expression explicitly ends with `cvec`.
- in `observeEvent({input$colour_pal` the `cvec` value is lost at the end of the execution of the observer; if you want to store it globally use `<<-` or make `cvec` a `reactiveValues()`.
- in `renderText` the print statement takes over the output.

> Is that because [...] shiny auto runs output$make_shape so it is not out of date?

Shiny runs `output$make_shape` because it calls `set_colour` which depends on `input$colour_pal`

> I wish that the "Colour Palette" dropdown only activates the observeEvent for input$colour_pal.

If you want to keep it as a function (my preference), I would not to use `input$` inside but pull the function outside Shiny and pass `colour_pal` as an argument.

If you want to keep `input$`, transform it into a reactive:

```
set_colour <- reactive({
    if (input$colour_pal == "Orange") {
        cvec <- heat.colors(2048)
    } else if (input$colour_pal == "Yellow") {
        cvec <- rainbow(2048, s = 1, v = 1, start = 0.03, end = 0.19, alpha = 1.0)
    } else if (input$colour_pal == "Blue") {
        cvec <- rainbow(2048, s = 1, v = 1, start = 0.48, end = 0.866, alpha = 1.0)
    } else if (input$colour_pal == "Grey") {
        cvec <- grey(seq(0, 1, length = 50))
    } else if (input$colour_pal == "Dark Green with Blue Streaks") {
        cvec <- rainbow(2048, s = 1, v = 0.4, start = 0.333, end = 0.7, alpha = 1.0)
    } else if (input$colour_pal == "Dark Green with Yellow Streaks") {
        yellow <- rainbow(2048, s = 1, v = 1, start = 0.03, end = 0.19, alpha = 1.0)
        dgb <- rainbow(2048, s = 1, v = 0.4, start = 0.333, end = 0.7, alpha = 1.0)
        dgb[1400: 2048] <- yellow[1400: 2048]
        cvec <- dgb
    }

    cvec
})

# Look for colour dropdown
observeEvent({
    input$colour_pal
}, {
    print("colour")
    cvec <- set_colour()
})

output$make_shape <- renderText({
    print("make_shape")
    isolate(set_colour())
})
```

The new problem is what you did not indicate what you want to happen to `output$make_shape` (i.e, reacts to what?). I used `isolate` above, but that makes it useless.